# What's wrong with my SQL query? (Crystal Reports)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, ms-access-2010, oledb, vb.net-2010

I have this code that works and displayed all data in "Sales".

```
MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Sales FROM tblFuelTransactionLogs where Year(Created_Date)='" & year & "' and Month(Created_Date)='" & month & "'"
```

But if I change it to *"SELECT SUM(Sales) ..."*, no data are displayed in my report.

I'm quite positive I need a formula or another field for me to be able to display this.

Any ideas, reactions, inputs welcome!

Answer (score 0):

i think the error is there Year(Created_Date)='"&year&"' and why are you using '&'.
try this query  with Year(Created_Date)='"+year+"'
i think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! It's an OLEDB command. And it works except SELECT SUM(). Anyway I'll try it.

Comment: Ampersands are the VB concatenation operator for strings. That shouldn't be the source of your problem especially when you say the query works without the SUM function.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used Crystal Reports but you might have to alias you sum column as Sales so that your report recognizes it.

```
MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(Sales) AS Sales FROM tblFuelTransactionLogs where Year(Created_Date)='" & year & "' and Month(Created_Date)='" & month & "'"
```